# Using a join operation with conditionals

Tags: sql-server, join, string

I have two tables that I'm working with in my database. I am using SQL Server 2014.

- One is 'versions', that contains version_id, version_number,
  start_date, end_date and server_id.
- The other is 'features', which contains feature_id, feature_info and
  version_id. version_id is a foreign key to the version_id in
  'versions', where it is a PK.

I'm trying to get something like:

**"X, Y, Z are in version 1.0.

"....... are in version 1.2.**

and then if a version does not have a new feature:

**"Version 2.2 has no new features."**

Right now, I don't have any versions without features, but I plan on adding some to test this out.

Here is the output I'm currently getting with my code (I don't care about the singular/plural issues, i.e. 'Version 1.7 has email client'):

**Version 1.0       has web functionality, Version 1.1       has user interface, Version 1.7       has email client, Version 1.7       has voice control functionality, Version 2.0       has bug fixes.**

There happens to be 7 spaces in between commas. This is less important, but would still be nice to be able to fix.

*Also, if I wanted to turn this into a stored procedure, would I just add, 'create procedure x', followed by 'begin' and 'as' after my variable declaration, and then an 'end' at the end of the code?

```
DECLARE @result varchar(1000)

SET @result = ''

BEGIN TRY

    SELECT @result = @result + 'Version ' + version_number + 'has ' +      feature_info + ', ' 
    FROM features join versions on versions.version_id = features.version_id
    SELECT substring(@result, 0, len(@result) - 1)

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'THere was an error getting feature info'
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that - SQL Server 2014. Also, server_id, as well as start and end date are probably not necessary for anyone trying to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `FOR XML PATH()` construct to create the list of features.

For instance:

```
USE tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Features') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Features;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Versions') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Versions;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Versions
(
    VersionID INT NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , VersionNumber DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
    , StartDate DATETIME NOT NULL
    , EndDate DATETIME NULL
    , ServerID INT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Features
(
    FeatureID INT NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , FeatureInfo VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL 
    , VersionID INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Versions(VersionID)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Versions(VersionNumber, StartDate, EndDate, ServerID)
VALUES (1.0,'2016-03-22T00:00:00', '2016-03-23T00:00:00', 1001)
    , (2.0,'2016-03-23T00:00:00', '2016-03-24T00:00:00', 1001)
    , (2.1,'2016-03-24T00:00:00', NULL, 1001);

INSERT INTO dbo.Features (FeatureInfo, VersionID)
VALUES ('blah', 1)
    , ('blee', 1)
    , ('bloh', 2);

;WITH Deets
AS
(
    SELECT VersionNumber = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), v.VersionNumber, 0)
        , Features = STUFF((SELECT TOP(2147483647) ', ' + f.FeatureInfo
        FROM dbo.Features f
        WHERE f.VersionID = v.VersionID
        ORDER BY f.FeatureID
        FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 1,2,'')
    FROM dbo.Versions v
)
SELECT 'Version ' + d.VersionNumber + ' has ' + 
    CASE WHEN d.Features IS NULL THEN 'no features' 
        ELSE d.Features 
    END
FROM Deets d;
```

This returns a nice list, like:

[image]

Notice several things from my code above:

- I always specify the schema
- I use upper case for the SQL keywords
- I use Camel Case for column names
- The values I specified for the date columns are in ISO format, which makes it easier for SQL Server to understand, and prevents errors.